# Button background changes when the value is 0 and the value is max (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to change the background color of the button when the value is 0 and the maximum value. I have made the code as below but it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this problem?

when i add this code in initial conditioning, it doesn't work. When i click + value dissapear

```
if( sum == 0 ){
   $('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', '#dadada');
}
```

The condition what i want:
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".base-quantity .btn").on("click", function () {

        var $button = $(this);
        var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
        var sum = 0;

        $('.base-quantity input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        });
        
        if(sum==0){
          $('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', '#dadada');
        }else if ($button.hasClass('btn__increment') && sum < 10) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
            $('btn__decrement').css('background-color', 'blue');
        } else if ($button.hasClass('btn__decrement')) {
            // nilai tidak bisa berkurang jika dibawah 0
            if (oldValue > 0) {
                var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
            } else {
                newVal = 0;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);

    });

})
```

```css
.base-quantity{
    background-color: rgba(239,239,239,0.3);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.base-quantity input{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

 .base-quantity .btn{
    background-color: #cc4645 ;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="base-quantity">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn__decrement">-</button>
   <input type="text" id="quantityVal" value="0" disabled>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn__increment">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think there is error here $('btn__decrement').css('background-color', '#dadada'); btn__decrement is not a tag use $('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', '#dadada');

Comment: but there is a strange behavior, take a look at my snippet above. The value disappears when I click + @Sirjiskit

Answer (score 0):

> when i add this code in initial conditioning, it doesn't work

```
if( sum == 0 ){
   $('btn__decrement').css('background-color', '#dadada');
}
```

Instead of

```
$('btn__decrement').css('background-color', '#dadada');
```

use

```
$('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', '#dadada');
Update
```

I don't know what you want to achieve but but add this snap to you code may be it will give you a hint

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            if (sum == 0) {
                $('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', '#dadada');
            }
            $('.btn__increment').click(function () {
                var oldValue = parseFloat($("#quantityVal").val());
                sum = oldValue + 1;
                if (sum < 10) {
                    $('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', 'blue');
                }
                $("#quantityVal").val(sum);
            });
            $('.btn__decrement').click(function () {
                var oldValue = parseFloat($("#quantityVal").val());

                if (sum > 0) {
                    sum = oldValue - 1;
                    $('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', 'blue');
                }
                if (sum == 0) {
                    $('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', '#dadada');
                }
                $("#quantityVal").val(sum);
            });
        })
```

Comment: but there is a strange behavior, take a look at my snippet above. The value disappears when I click +

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a variable hoisting issue, as you have declared `var newVal` in if blocks so `var` variable will get hoisted so you will not get an error as a variable is `not defined` but it will be `undefined` as you are initializing them in the `if-else` condition and on the first click, those will not get executed so the value of `newVal` remains `undefined` that is why you see blank on the click.

I have provided the fix int the below code ,by the way i am not sure what are you trying to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style>
         .base-quantity{
         background-color: rgba(239,239,239,0.3);
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         }
         .base-quantity input{
         height: 100%;
         width: 100%;
         text-align: center;
         border: none;
         background-color: transparent;
         }
         .base-quantity .btn{
         background-color: #cc4645 ;
         color: #fff;
         border-radius: 0;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="base-quantity">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn__decrement">-</button>
         <input type="text" id="quantityVal" value="0" disabled>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn__increment">+</button>
      </div>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             
              $('.btn__increment').css('background-color', 'blue');
              
             $(".base-quantity .btn").on("click", function () {
                 
             var $button = $(this);
             var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
             var sum = 0;
             var newVal=0;
             $('.base-quantity input[type="text"]').each(function () {
                 sum += Number($(this).val());
             });
            
            if ($button.hasClass('btn__increment') && sum < 10) {
                 newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
                 $('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', 'blue');
             } else if ($button.hasClass('btn__decrement')) {
                 if (oldValue > 0) {
                      newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
                 } else {
                     newVal = 0;
                 }
             } else {
                 return false;
             }
             
             
             if(newVal==0){
                 clicked=false;
                  $('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', '#dadada');
               $('.btn__increment').css('background-color', 'blue');
             }
             else if(newVal>0 && newVal<=10){
                 $('.btn__decrement').css('background-color', 'blue');
             }
             
             if(newVal < 10){
              $('.btn__increment').css('background-color', 'blue');
             }
             
             else if(newVal == 10){
                $('.btn__increment').css('background-color', '#dadada');
             }
             $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
         
         });
         
         })
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code above still doesn't work. You ask what I want, what I want is clear above. That I want when the value is 0, the color decrement button changes. And when the value reaches the maximum value (10), the increment button will change color. In addition, the button color is normal

Comment: @Fikryrmdhna I have updated the code as per your requirement.

Comment: still not work. have you tried jsfiddle or something?

Comment: i have added code snippet please run and check @Fikryrmdhna

Comment: Currently in your snippet, the button turns blue when the value is 1, which I wanted at the start (0). And when the value reaches the maximum value (10), the increment button doesn't turn blue, it should change

Comment: okay will update code for the same @Fikryrmdhna

Comment: I have updated the code as per your need again but you need to organize the code in somewhat better please try to do that by yourself. @Fikryrmdhna

Comment: I give an image that describes the conditions I want in the post above

Comment: sorry, @Fikryrmdhna please try to develop it by yourself. I will help out if you face any issues.